# Typescript not enforcing type with in function parameter

Tags: typescript, casting

I have this very simple function that accept 3 integers, add them together and print the sum out to a console.

```
function add(n1, n2, n3) {
    var sum : number = n1 + n2 + n3;

    console.log(sum);
}
```

My assumption was `sum` is an integer therefore it enforce the type matching. So i tried this.

```
add(1,2,"Henok");
```

TypeScript does not complain, it simply print out `3Henok`. Why?

---

Answered in the comment blow by **toskv** he mentioned two thing

> actually what you are writing there is var sum:number = (1 as any) +
>   (2 as any) + ('hehe3' as any) because the types of the parameters are
>   not specified and they default to any

and to enforce compile time complaining he add this suggestion

> you can enable the noImplicitAny option when compiling and tsc will
>   complain that you have not properly typed your code.

That works for me. thank you toskv.

Comment: uhm.. how have you tried this? type checking is only enforced at compile time. at runtime it's all just javascript.

Comment: @toskv I do understand it's only a compile time checking. I put the result just to say it do pass "compile time checking"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter also should specify type in typescript in order to see compilation error.

```
function add(n1:number, n2:number, n3:number) {
    var sum : number = n1 + n2 + n3;

    console.log(sum);
}

add(1,2, "Henok"); // compilation error
```

Thanks to tosky

By default parameters/variables that are not marked with any type are considered as "any" , any is literally anything (any type) and no type check is performed on any.

Don't confuse `any` with `object`, if you are using something like C# then any is similar to `dynamic` where type is determined at runtime.

So, expression

```
var sum:number = n1 + n2 + n3
```

is actually

```
var sum:number = (n1 as any) + (n2 as any) + (n3 as any)
```

Comment: it's worth mentioning that by default the parameters have the type any

Comment: That i know, if you write `var sum : number = 1 + 2 + "Henok";'`it doesn't work (compile time error) but not inside the function. that what i do not expected to see.

Comment: actually what you are writing there is `var sum:number = (1 as any) + (2 as any) + ('hehe3' as any)` because the types of the parameters are not specified and they default to `any`

Comment: Ohh i see, I assumed the compiler worked out the correct type at compilation not at runtime.

Comment: you can enable the `noImplicitAny` option when compiling and tsc will complain that you have not properly typed your code. :)

Comment: @toskv Thank you so much, that was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: if @AkashKava won't update his answer with this info I'll make another one myself so you properly solve the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running typescript validation on JavaScript files, don't forget to add `checkJs: true` in `tsconfig.json`, or to add `// @ts-check` to the very top (i.e. before imports) of your files.